# NUnit how to test parameters passed to a object contructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have methods which looks like this:

```
public A Method(int a, int b){
    return new A().AMethod(a, b);
}
```

Now I'm testing it via test that object I get has the expected values after been operated 'a' and 'b' for AMethod, but for me this look like a integration test where I'm testing the first method and the AMethod inside. I'm wondering how can I test my Method isolated to know 'a' and 'b' are passed to AMethod after create a new object A, and they are passed in that order in not for instance inverted.

Comment: Why is your instance method returning the value of a new instances' instance method?

Comment: A is a DTO and a, b are items from down tiers. AMethod sets A properties whith values from a and b.

Comment: Why does it instantiate a new `A` though? Can't it just call `AMethod`?

Comment: Because we want to retrieve a new object A filled with data from a and b.

Comment: So does `AMethod` also return a new instance? I ask because that means you're creating an instance, calling a method which creates another instance, and that method calls an instance method of that object to create another instance and return it..

Answer (score 1):

You can always use mocking framework to test it. Create mock using i.e MOQ framework. Than you can test the parameters. It would be something like this

This is not the exact code it has some errors but can give you an idea.

```
 var mocmethod = new Mock<IMethodA>(pass your parameters here)
mockmethod.setup=(x=>x.a(It.Isany<int>)......).Returns(A), 
mockmethod.Verify(r=>r.a(It.Is<int>(r=>r.b == "Something"), It.Is<int>(i=>i > 17)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 solutions here:

1. **Introduce `A` factory dependency.**
   The responsibility to create new `A` instances can be delegated to thir-party interface. E.g. it could be `IAFactory`. `Method()` should use this factory to create new `A` instance rather than create `A` directly.
   In that case you can stub `IAFactory`: It should return `A` mock. And you can test that `AMethod` is called with appropriate parameters.
2. **Assert the result of `AMethod()` execution.**
   E.g.: if `AMethod()` initializes 2 properties (`PropA` and `PropB`) of `A` instance, then test should check that those properties contain valid values.
   In that case test doesn't consider in which way the properies are initialized actually. It just checks that the final result matches to expected.